# Does python json output values have maximum length for json_decode (php) to handle?

Tags: php, python, json

I am trying to write a php code that takes coefficients from a html form, sends them to a python algorithm that returns a json object. That object is a list of player names, basically {"Ji" : "Firstname Lastname"} for i from 1 to 15.
The python code (interface.py) I have to create this json is :

```
import json 
i=0
for joueur in best_team:
   i+=1
   output["J%s"%(i)]=joueur['nom']
out=json.dumps(output)
print(out)
```

best_team is a list of player dictionnaries with data on them. My player names don't involve any non ASCII characters or whatever.

My php code is the following :

```
$command = "python interface.py";
$command .=  " $coeff1 $coeff2 $coeff3 $coeff4 $coeff5 $coeff6 $coeff7    $coeff8 $coeff9 $coeff10  2>&1";


$pid = popen( $command,"r");
while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
$data = fread($pid, 256);
$data= json_decode($data) ;
echo $data->J1;

flush();
ob_flush();
echo "<script>window.scrollTo(0,99999);</script>";
usleep(100000);

}
pclose($pid);
```

I call the coefficients from the html and then send back the results via a js file.
But I just get the following error : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.
Nothing wrong with the js file because if I try instead :

```
$string = '{"foo": "bar", "cool": "attributlong"}';
$result = json_decode($string);
echo $result ->cool;
```

It works. 
Also if I have instead in my python file :

```
out={"foo":"bar","word":"longerthaneightcharacters"}
out=json.dumps(out)
print(out)
```

It works as well (replacing `J1` by `word` in php code of course).
And funny enough, if i have in python:

```
output={}
i=0
for joueur in best_team:
   i+=1
   output["J%s"%(i)]="short"
   output["J%s"%(i)]=str(output["J%s"%(i)])

out=json.dumps(output)
print(out)
```

It works, and if I replace `"short"` by `"longerthaneightcharacters"` it doesn't work anymore.

So basically my question is, why is there a maximum number of characters in my output loop and how can I bypass it ? Thanks, I am very confused.

Comment: The obvious question is why you're funneling requests through PHP to python when it would take all of about 3 minutes to translate the python code to PHP and handle it directly?

Comment: i am not sure i understand what you mean. The python code is just an extract. `best_team` is the result of a genetic algorithm that I wrote in python. I don't know php well enough to code such things directly in php. And even if used `best_team` as output and treated it in php it is a list of dictionnaries so I would face the same issues.